# Using an accumulator to sum up numbers in F#

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, f#

I'm trying to solve a problem that requires me to sum up 2 numbers but I have to use an accumulator in my function.
This is the math formula:

```
sum(m, n) = m + (m + 1) + (m + 2) + · · · + (m + (n − 1)) + (m + n)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
let rec g (m, n) = 
    let rec gAcc m n a = 
        match n with
        | 0 -> a + m
        | n -> gAcc m (n-1) (a+n+m)
    let result = gAcc n m 0   
    result // returned by g
```

An example would be
`g(1,2)` should return 5.
I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here? Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to work fine. What's the problem?

Comment: According to your formula `g(1,2)` = 1+ 1+1 + 1+2 = 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've swapped the `m` and `n` arguments when calling `gAcc` initially.

```
gAcc n m 0
```

should be

```
gAcc m n 0
```

This is one reason why short and similar variable names like `m` and `n` aren't a great idea.

You also don't need the `result` binding, you might want to use a simple `if` expression instead of `match`, and treat `n = 0` the same as `n > 0` since `m + 0 = m`:

```
let rec g (m, n) = 
    let rec gAcc m i a = 
        if i >= 0 then
            gAcc m (i-1) (a+i+m)
        else
            a
    gAcc m n 0
```